# Call async method multiple time in window form application

Tags: c#

I have following method , i want to call this method multiple at same time. and want to check if any of the result string contains "Start" text then move control forward otherwise wait for "Start" in any result string.

```
public async Task<string> ProcessURLAsync(string url, ExtendedWebClient oExtendedWebClient, string sParam)
{
    ExtendedWebClient oClient = new ExtendedWebClient(false);
    oClient.CookieContainer = oExtendedWebClient.CookieContainer;
    oClient.LastPage = "https://www.example.co.in/test/getajax.jsf";
    byte[] PostData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sParam);
    Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows T 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36");
    Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    oClient.Headers.Remove("X-Requested-With");
    oClient.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    var byteArray = await oClient.UploadDataTaskAsync(url, PostData);
    string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
    return result;
}
```

please suggest way to achieve this.

Comment: i used Task.WaitAll. it works. but it waits for all tasks to finish. what i want if any one finish and it contains  string "Start" then move forward otherwise wait another to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do, is edit your Task so that it runs in a while loop and only exits when your value is found.

Then, create a list of tasks using a loop, iterating through as many tasks as you want it to run simultaneously .

Then you can use `Task.WhenAny`

```
public async Task<string> ProcessURLAsync(string url, ExtendedWebClient oExtendedWebClient, string sParam)
{
    string result = "";
    while (!result.Contains("Start"))
    {
        ExtendedWebClient oClient = new ExtendedWebClient(false);
        oClient.CookieContainer = oExtendedWebClient.CookieContainer;
        oClient.LastPage = "https://www.example.co.in/test/getajax.jsf";
        byte[] PostData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sParam);
        Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows T 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36");
        Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        oClient.Headers.Remove("X-Requested-With");
        oClient.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        var byteArray = await oClient.UploadDataTaskAsync(url, PostData);
        result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) //Run 20 at a time.
            taskList.Add(ProcessURLAsync(url, webClient, "whatever"));
        await Task.WhenAny(taskList);
        //Value found! Continue...
```

Comment: i am new to task , if possible can you please post sample code.

Comment: above loop calls method and waits to complete. i want to hit this method same time with different parameter.

Comment: What parameter differs?

Comment: ProcessURLAsync(url, webClient, "whatever"); ProcessURLAsync(url, webClient, "param2"); ProcessURLAsync(url, webClient, "param3");

Comment: Then modify the loop to suit your need. If you have an array of different parameters, loop through those instead.

Comment: as above method need to be hits 3 times parallel.

Comment: but in loop this will be executed one by one . i want it to hit all array param same time.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a loop, either. If you only have 3, then use `taskList.Add` 3 times and scrap the loop.

Comment: I dont know why taskList.Result not available.